# awk to count number of occurrences in a Column and print in new column

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a large file in the following format:

```
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    58334   58504   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    54573   54723   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    52624   52680   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    52413   52551   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    28715   28784   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    26768   26814   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    25856   25914   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    25374   25727   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    70772   70841   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    70672   70687   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    70494   70586   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    69020   69335   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    68831   68928   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    68251   68721   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    89665   89909   .   +   .   GeneID:110014398
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    91117   91579   .   +   .   GeneID:110014398
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    119534  120075  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    118137  118262  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    117700  117831  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    117326  117490  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461
```

I want following desired out put

```
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    58334   58504   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:1 
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    54573   54723   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:2
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    52624   52680   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:3
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    52413   52551   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:4
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    28715   28784   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:5
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    26768   26814   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:6
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    25856   25914   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:7
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    25374   25727   .   -   .   GeneID:110014915    exon_number:8
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    70772   70841   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276    exon_number:1
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    70672   70687   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276    exon_number:2
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    70494   70586   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276    exon_number:3
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    69020   69335   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276    exon_number:4
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    68831   68928   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276    exon_number:5
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    68251   68721   .   -   .   GeneID:110017276    exon_number:6
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    89665   89909   .   +   .   GeneID:110014398    exon_number:1
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    91117   91579   .   +   .   GeneID:110014398    exon_number:2
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    119534  120075  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461    exon_number:1
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    118137  118262  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461    exon_number:2
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    117700  117831  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461    exon_number:3
NC_019859.2 Gnomon  exon    117326  117490  .   -   .   GeneID:101166461    exon_number:4
```

I tried this command and got.

```
awk '{a[$9]++}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' 
GeneID:110014915 8
GeneID:110017276 6
GeneID:110014398 2
GeneID:101166461 4
```

Thanks in advance, looking forward for a positive response.

Comment: Good that you showed us what you have tried, try to wrap your samples in code tags too(see how your post looks now) there is a button `{}` while editing your post, cheers and keep learning, keep sharing on this great site SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{print $0,"exon_number:"++a[$9]}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation of above code:***

`print`: Is `awk`'s out of the box utility for print the variable/line.

`$0`: In `awk` language `$0` is current line(so printing current line).

`,`: comma is separator here which will enter a space between `$0` and next string on output.

`"exon_number:"`: Printing string `exon_number`now as per OP's output.

`++a[$9]`: Here I am creating an array named a whose index is 9th column and `++` before it makes sure first its value increases and then it prints its value of array a(which will be simply occurrence number of 9th column).

In case you need to have output as TAB separated then change `awk` to `awk BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` in above code too.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$NF!=prev{cnt=0; prev=$NF} {print $0, "exon_number:"++cnt}' file
```

The difference between this and Ravinders answer is that his will create an array indexed by every key (GeneID) value in the input file while the above will only use 2 variables and so use far less memory. His will work for an unsorted file, mine will only work if the key values are grouped together as shown in your sample input. Functionally the memory issue will only matter if your input file is huge.